# Reducing the duration of this COUNT() query

Tags: performance, sql-server-2014, query-performance

I have a table with 2,161,524 rows. I think the counting query is taking too long.

```
select count(mcon_codigo_pk) from tbMovimentoConta
-- count = 2,161,524
-- time = 9 seconds

select count(1) from tbMovimentoConta 
where con_codigo_fk = 1 
and mcon_data between '2015-01-05' and '2016-01-06'
-- count = 1,034,729 
-- time = 13 seconds
```

Details:

- The column `con_codigo_fk` is `bigint` and has a foreign key index (non-clustered)
- The column `mcon_data` is `datetime` and has index (non-clustered)
- The table has an auto-increment PK (clustered index)
- There's more three foreign that has index (all indexes was created by Entity Framework)

Index creating script

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_mcon_data] ON [dbo].[tbMovimentoConta]
(
    [mcon_data] ASC
)
WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF
    , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
    , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
    , DROP_EXISTING = OFF
    , ONLINE = OFF
    , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
    , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
);
GO
```

[image]

My computer has 8GB RAM and a Core i7 running Windows 10.

Are my queries really taking a long time or they are on the average expected time? If they are taking a long time, what can I do to make them faster?

Comment: Why do you need a bigint for a FK?

Comment: None of your indexes cover the query. Posting the plan would be helpful. It's either using the ix_mcon_data and doing a lookup for each row to evaluate the con_codigo_fk, looking at the con_condigo_fk index and doing a lookup for the mcon_data, or doing a clustered index scan on the PK and filtering out results. Ideally you'd cover the query with an index on mcon_data and con_codigo_fk. You'd have to look at perf with that for insert/update though.

Comment: My boss decided to be bigint. He said because the range is bigger. I cannot change that. I agree with you. Everywhere is bigint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities for a covering index of the query:

- a composite index on `(con_codigo_fk, mcon_data)`. This would cover all similar queries.
  If you add this index, you can (most probably) safely remove the index on `(con_codigo_fk)` and the new one will be used instead. The other index on `(mcon_data)` can be used by different queries, so I wouldn't remove it.

  Code to add the index:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ix__con_codigo_fk__mcon_data       -- choose a name
    ON dbo.tbMovimentoConta
    (con_codigo_fk, mcon_data) ;
  ```
- a filtered index on `(mcon_data) WHERE (con_codigo_fk = 1)`. This would of course be useful only for queries with the specific value (`1`).
  The use cases for such indexes are much more rare so it's probably not useful to you.

Another issue is that you are using `BETWEEN` with a datetime type. This will give you inaccurate results, as it will include results with the exact datetime `'2016-01-06' 00:00:00'`

It's better to use inclusive-exclusive ranges:

```
select count(*) 
from tbMovimentoConta 
where con_codigo_fk = 1 
  and mcon_data >= '2015-01-05' 
  and mcon_data  < '2016-01-06' ;
```

[@Aaron Bertrand](http://stackexchange.com/users/24165/aaron-bertrand) has blogged about this with much more detailed explanation: **[What do `BETWEEN` and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**

---

Another issue - that the index isn't trying to address - is that while the time needed for the query with the `WHERE` condition might be explained by a bad plan and lack of appropriate index, the time for the 1st query, the whole table count (9 seconds) sounds a bit too much. (and the 1 second for the query after the index added is high, too).

I would be speculating without further details as the explanation might be from numerous different reasons (general/memory SQL Server settings, high load on the server, wide clustered index, etc) so I suggest you either add more details on the question or post a new question (with the `CREATE TABLE` script if the issue is only for queries involving this table).

Comment: For option one, should I remove the existing index on con_codigo_fk and mcon_data?

Comment: Yes for the 1st one and no for the 2nd.

Comment: I'm really dummy on this. In SQL Management Studio shoud I add the columns on "Index key columns" or "included columns" tabs?

Comment: Added statement for creating index.

Comment: That worked man! Thank you so much. Now it takes one second or less

Comment: It's still a bit high. What is the clustered index on the table? Can you edit the question and add the whole `CREATE TABLE` script (and all the indexes)?

Comment: I said one second or less because I can't count. It's really very fast now.

Comment: Ah, OK. I though that the SSMS gives you an accurate timing, in milliseconds.

Comment: I will ask a new question, because this worked, but I have other queries that are slow. I this new question I will provide more details.